# RealTime kernel on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, real-time, raspbian

I'm trying to install a realtime kernel version of Linux on a Raspberry Pi 4 using Raspbian 32 bit, but following this procedure I encounter some problems:

1. **~$** mkdir ~/rpi-kernel
2. **~$** cd ~/rpi-kernel
3. **~rpi-kernel$** mkdir rt-kernel
4. **~/rpi-kernel$** git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git -b rpi-4.19.y-rt
5. **~/rpi-kernel$** git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git
6. **~/rpi-kernel$** ARCH=arm
7. **~/rpi-kernel$** CROSS_COMPILE=~/rpi-kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
8. **~/rpi-kernel$** INSTALL_MOD_PATH=~/rpi-kernel/rt-kernel
9. **~/rpi-kernel$** INSTALL_DTBS_PATH=~/rpi-kernel/rt-kernel
10. **~/rpi-kernel$** KERNEL=kernel7l
11. **~/rpi-kernel$** cd ~/rpi-kernel/linux/
12. **~/rpi-kernel/linux/$** make bcm2711_defconfig
13. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** make -j4 zImage
14. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** make -j4 modules
15. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** make -j4 dtbs
16. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** make -j4 modules_install
17. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** make -j4 dtbs_install
18. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb /boot/
19. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/overlays
20. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/overlays
21. **~/rpi-kernel/linux$** sudo cp arch/arm/boot/zImage /boot/kernelname.img
22. Assign "kernel=kernelname.img" into /boot/config.txt
23. Reboot the system.

But when I reboot the system, it promps "cgroup2: unknown option "memory_recursiveprot" and I don't see the desktop (only black screen), but the processor still performs some activities (green light that lights up occasionally).

What am I wrong? If I perform the same operations using a 5.10 kernel version everything is fine.

Comment: The "memory_recursiveprot" cgroup2 option does not exist before the 5.7 kernel.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ros-realtime/linux-real-time-kernel-builder